# SKAction.customActionWithDuration Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I try next code but get following error: "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'". Where am I wrong?

```
let moveLeft = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(0.0, actionBlock: {node: SKNode!, elapsedTime: CGFloat) -> Void in
            node.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.5)
          })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in a closure are like a tuple, they need brackets on both sides. Also you should explicitly unwrap the node's physicsBody (or use `if let` if it might be nil).

```
let moveLeft = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(0.0, actionBlock: { (node: SKNode!, elapsedTime: CGFloat) -> Void in
    node.physicsBody!.velocity=CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5)
})
```